# Groovy CliBuilder.parse(args) is not working to split the list of arguments

Tags: groovy

I have the next list of arguments, and I would like to split them in different arguments:

```
[-r, /company/target, -s, http://192.133.0.5:8080, -a, admin:pass, -i, dev, filePath]
```

And this is my code:

```
    cli.i(args:1,'target')
    cli.s(args:1,'url')
    cli.a(args:1,'credentials')

    def opts = cli.parse(args)
    System.out.println("optsA:::" + opts.a)
    System.out.println("optsS:::" + opts.s)
```

but I'm getting the next answer:

```
optsA:::false
optsS:::false
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have to define all possible options otherwise CliBuilder stops on finding unknown one.

you could set `cli.stopAtNonOption=false` just before parse - then parser will print an error on unknown option.

```
def cli = new CliBuilder()
cli.r(args:1,'target')  // << missing definition
cli.i(args:1,'env')
cli.s(args:1,'url')
cli.a(args:1,'credentials')
cli.stopAtNonOption=false

String[] args = ['-r', '/company/target', '-s', 'http://192.133.0.5:8080', '-a', 'admin:pass', '-i', 'dev', 'filePath']
def opts = cli.parse(args)
println opts.a
println opts.s
```

if you are using clibuilder not in command line - probably better to use `apache.commons.cli` that is included into groovy 2.5+

```
import org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser
import org.apache.commons.cli.Options

String[] args = ['-r', '/company/target', '-s', 'http://192.133.0.5:8080', '-a', 'admin:pass', '-i', 'dev', 'filePath']

def opts = new Options()
    .addOption('r',true,'')
    .addOption('i',true,'')
    .addOption('s',true,'')
    .addOption('a',true,'')
def cmd = new DefaultParser().parse(opts,args,false)
println cmd.getOptionValue('s')
println cmd.getOptionValue('a')
println cmd.getArgs()
```

this code will throw exception on unknown option

Comment: Is this example working?

Comment: if you uncomment line `cli.r(...)` it will work

Comment: I got the next error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'a' on null object

Comment: if you use `cli.stopAtNonOption=false` opts will be null on parsing failure and in StdOut you should see the error why it failed.

Comment: So in order to make the example work I need to define all the options?

Comment: right you have to define all possible options otherwise it will not be parsed